# Respective: Lines connect a circle and two respective squares

Tags: science, correspondence

> Lines connect a circle and two respective squares.

This use of “respective” strikes me as odd. The writer says he uses “respective” so that the sentence entails Case 1 below and precludes Case 2.

Does this use of “respective” accomplish that goal?

If not, what is the simplest way to do so?

Case 1:  Square --- Circle --- Square

Case 2:   Circle --- Square --- Square

(Read each set of three hyphens as a line.)

Comment: A circle is connected by lines to two squares.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb 'respectively' is far easier to deal with:

> Anne and Bob own dogs called Xerxes and Yappie respectively.

So A --> X  and B --> Y where the mapping descriptor here is 'own/s'.

(Of course, this may be extended to C --> Z etc.)

With the adjective, the *A associates (possibly bijectively, eg 'is married to') with X and B associates in the same way with Y* conditions have still to apply, or the word is meaningless.

> Anne and Bob took their respective dogs [(Xerxes and Yappie)] home.
>
> *Anne took her respective dogs home.

The usual dictionary definition

> respective  adj
>
> 1. belonging or relating separately to each of several people or things; several: *we took our respective ways home*. [[Collins E
>      D](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/respective)]

does not make it sufficiently clear that there have to be equal numbers of elements in each set

> (*Anne took her respective dogs home. Anne --> dog 1. ? --> dog 2 etc. )

I won't repeat the obvious better versions (including the one given by OP / 'the writer')

Answer (score 0):

> Lines connect a circle and two respective squares.

Without context, that sentence isn't meaningful.  It doesn't specify a particular arrangement of connections among the circle and squares.  Both of the connection examples mentioned in the question – that is,  Square‒Circle‒Square and Circle‒Square‒Square – are possible, and so is a triangular arrangement with the circle attached directly to each square and the squares to each other.

One might instead say

> For each square, a line connects it to the circle.

Avoiding all chance of misunderstanding requires somewhat lengthy, repetitious, and careful wording, of which the following is suggestive.

> A distinct line from each square connects that square to the circle

---

---

Following are examples of problematic forms.  While they can be interpreted to mean one line per square directly connects it to the circle, they can also be interpreted to instead mean a single line contacts the circle and both squares, with the three entities in any order:

> Each square is connected to the circle by a line.
>   A line connects each square to the circle.

Answer (score -1):

A first reading of that sentence leaves the intent of the writer unclear, because it is not possible to deduce exactly what he means from the inadequate information contained in the description. The inclusion of 'respective' is insufficient. (However, I imagine that the explanation of the cases which follows that description *will* clarify it for most readers.)

Nevertheless, it would have been better if he had worded it something like this:

> Lines connect the individual elements of **two respective sets of geometric shapes,** with each set of shapes consisting of a circle plus two squares.

This wording is impossible to misunderstand.

Comment: “This wording is impossible to misunderstand” is incorrect; I'm perfectly capable of misunderstanding the wording you give, several different ways, none of which coincide with my understanding of the scenario in the question.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Then I must congratulate you on the possession of such a superior faculty of misinterpretation.  :)

Comment: Yes the way I read that suggestion I get two sets of shapes.  Each of the two sets consists of a circle and two squares and each of the shapes is connected by lines to the shapes in the other set.